# How do I enqueue retina.js in a Wordpress child theme functions.php properly?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, retina.js

so I'm just discovering the world of Wordpress child themes, and it's especially promising for me since I'm editing more than just CSS (some php and js files.) I know my child theme is working properly because I copied over a 404.php page and made a few changes to the content and tried forcing a 404, and it gave me the new child theme's 404 page—so that so far we know is working.

Now I'm having an issue with enqueueing retina.js in my functions.php file in my child theme. My propblem being that I can't seem to figure out how to change the code so that it points to the retina.js file in the *child* theme, not the *parent*. I know that at least the enqueue works because it's only in my functions.php in my child theme, and it isn't in my parent theme (otherwise it wouldn't work anyway.) And I have tested this by deleting the retina.js file from the parent theme, and noticing it obviously stops working, and then reuploading the file and getting the retina images.

I'll post the code below and I would greatly appreciate any help in getting it to point to the child theme file, and not the parent file. Thanks in advance!

```
<?php 


#-----------------------------------------------------------------#
# Enqueue retina.js
#-----------------------------------------------------------------#


add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'retina_support_enqueue_scripts' );
/**
 * Enqueueing retina.js
 *
 * This function is attached to the 'wp_enqueue_scripts' action hook.
 */
function retina_support_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'retina_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/retina.js', '', '', true );
}


?>
```

**EDIT:** @Veelen answered my question below, and for those who are curious, this is how my functions.php in my child theme ended up looking with the fix:

```
<?php 


#-----------------------------------------------------------------#
# Register/Enqueue retina.js
#-----------------------------------------------------------------#


add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'retina_support_enqueue_scripts' );
/**
 * Enqueueing retina.js
 *
 * This function is attached to the 'wp_enqueue_scripts' action hook.
 */
function retina_support_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'retina_js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/retina.js', '', '', true );
}


?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use get_stylesheet_directory() instead of get_template_directory_uri().

Comment: I'm travelling back home today, but as soon as I get a chance to sit down and tinker with it I'll update the post and let you know! =)

Comment: Hey @veelen, I think I was able to get it working with that fix. It didn't take at first, and it finally started working after I had changed "wp_enqueue_script" to "wp_enqueue_scripts" on the bottom line (which broke the site by adding the extra "s") and back to the original instance without an S. I also was able to find several tutorials online explaining the difference, and "get_stylesheet" is meant when it's a child theme, so that makes sense. Excellent work and thanks for the help.